# Iframe cookies in safari

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, safari

I am having a problem in my project which is based on iframe. It works in a way that my user gets the embed code for particular broadcasts and paste them on third-party websites. The embed code creates an iframe on third party websites and my application run in it. The application is connected with facebook so user must login with facebook to use the application  when user visits first time the see a facebook login button by pressing they get a popup and logged in with facebook. After they login i get their information using graph api and set it in a session. All this scenario works fine in all browsers but cookies are not set in safari.

I am using codeigniter for my project please help me. I have tried setting a p3p header but it also didnt work.

Comment: Better answers are available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Carefully

I am  using CodeIgnitesession library and that is different than normal PHP’s session. I found that for each visit of the user, the server can’t track the session and regenerating new session id each time. Very weird situation for us. As we coded all over based on CodeIginter’s session library’s function so its not optimal solution for us to remove the codes and use PHP’s native session. Because in that case there is high possibility to generate new bugs. After lots of searching in the net at last we found a wrapper class for CodeIgniter.

This wrapper class is named Native session . It uses the same functions name like CodeIgniter’s Session class, but it used PHP’s native session on the back end. As our project is running on Dedicated Server so we are not worried about the session security. We replaced CodeIgniter’s Session class by this Native session  class and it solved our problem.

So if you’re facing this type of session related problem by using CodeIgniter’s Session library, you can use the  Native session library to fix the problem. Hope it helps.