# My Facebook application doesnt work with cookies

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, cookies, safari

Internet Explorer sometimes doesn't keep cookies, and Safari is not working at all.

I decided to give up cookies,and pulling the "user id" from the signed-request data (for each request/page), that idea worked well only for my main page.

But when trying to see other pages in my app, I don't have the signed request anymore, and still cookies are making problems.

I don't know how other apps do that, but this looks impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging , Internet explorer needed a P3p header to accept cookies 
and safari problem solved like this

```
https://gist.github.com/586182

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working
```

well this took me a long time to find a solution for it 
thank you .

Answer (score 0):

here I Got same problem today in FB C# JS SDK

I Use Cookie-less session 
now its working perfectly

**Try Cookie-Less  Session**

Comment: i am using playframework ,so i dont know if cookies less exists there

Comment: this thread was very helpfull ,http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1835285/iframe-facebook-application-and-cookies-internet-explorer  ,ie is working but safari is not....

Comment: i used this header response.setHeader("P3P", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");