# Calling Facebook php SDK's setAccessToken followed by getUser fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios4

I use facebook's IOS SDK to get the users access token and then I send that to my web service which then, on the server side uses that token.

It passes the token to the Facebook PHP SDK and calls setAccessToken().

After that, it attempts to call getUser(), but the getUser fails as if the user has not actually logged in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with the facebook php api.
In Apple devices you cannot set third party cookies.
You will have to let the user interact with the third party.

Check this out:

[Safari 3rd party cookie iframe trick no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the access token you don't need `getUser()` and you can straight away use the `api()` method.. after you set `setAccessToken()` of course.