# Cookies don't work over WebSocket on Apple devices

Tags: ios, cookies, websocket, safari

Iv'e been setting and retrieving cookies over pre-WebSocket stage to identify a user. I assumed everything would work as over a typical HTTP exchange.

This has worked flawlessly on all browsers I've tested them on, but reports started coming in that on iPhones the sign-ins would not be retained at all, signifying that *cookies either were not set or sent back to the server*.

```golang
// fret not, safety checks removed for brevity

const (
    sessionKeyCookieName string = "session-key"
    webSocketPath        string = "/ws"
)

func serveWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var sessionKey [sha1.Size]byte
    var u *user
    for _, cookie := range r.Cookies() {
        if cookie.Name != sessionKeyCookieName {
            continue
        }
        slice, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cookie.Value)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        } else {
            copy(sessionKey[:], slice)
        }
    }
    u, _ = getUserBySessionKey(sessionKey)

    // regenerate key. TODO: does that add security?
    rand.Read(sessionKey[:])

    header := make(http.Header)
    header.Add("Set-Cookie", (&http.Cookie{
        Name:     sessionKeyCookieName,
        Value:    base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sessionKey[:]),
        MaxAge:   int(sessionLength.Seconds()),
        HttpOnly: true,
        Domain:   strings.SplitN(r.Host, ":", 2)[0],
    }).String())

    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, header)
    if err != nil {
        if _, ok := err.(websocket.HandshakeError); !ok {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        return
    }

    // do things to `user` so their messages go to where they're needed

    go c.writePump()
    c.readPump()
}
```

Headers as seen on Firefox network dev tool

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: eSazcZyZKj2dfa2UWSY+a4wThC8=
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: session-key=RNStK2z2gAsan7DyNKQ+efjyr7c=; Domain=redacted.org; Max-Age=259200; HttpOnly
```

Am I skipping some step that would allow Safari to store cookies, or is this an issue *upstream*<sup>1</sup>?

P.S. I'd really like to retain this approach, since I can use HTTP-only cookies and that mostly ensures that JavaScript has no access to them.

---

1. Looks like Gary is having [similar issues](https://forum.infiniteautomation.com/topic/1981/problem-using-websockets-with-safari-and-solution) as well. In short, cookies don't travel back over WebSockets.

Comment: Note that non-secure cookies and secure cookies are stored separately on Safari, preventing secure cookies from being exposed to non-secure connections. Trying to use `wss` from an `http` related cookie, or trying to use an `https` related cookie for a `ws` connection, is doomed to fail. Could it be that you're mixing TLS with non-TLS connections?

Comment: Can't be that, @Myst, i'm not using encryption right now.

Comment: Is the target hostname in any way special (e.g. "localhost", or a non-TLD)? Some browsers/clients have special handling for some of those, including inclusion of cookies (e.g. IE won't include a cookie if its domain property is "localhost"). Have you tested other hostnames? Just guessing :)

Comment: @HariLubovac added actual headers that get sent. It all happens on the same domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: it's the `HttpOnly` flag.

---

It appears that while some browsers *do* allow `Set-Cookie` header in a response for WebSocket connection to have `HttpOnly` flag, iOS Safari considers the situation as "non-HTTP" and blocks this.

Interestingly, while setting `HttpOnly` cookies is not possible, `HttpOnly` cookies are sent in request headers while connecting a WebSocket. This leaves a pair of options:

- Increase risk and omit `HttpOnly`;
- Set your cookies with another plain HTTP request, quite possibly one that doesn't even have a response body.

---

I'd consider iOS Safari's behavior to be incorrect compared to what's outlined in [RFC 6265 Storage model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3)

Answer (score 3):

If your `Set-Cookie` header works in other browsers my guess is it's an upstream issue, specifically iOS Safari has the ability to block cookies. By default iOS Safari blocks 3rd party cookies.

[Can a webpage in mobile Safari check whether Settings > Safari > Accept Cookies 'From visited' or 'Always' is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046997/can-a-webpage-in-mobile-safari-check-whether-settings-safari-accept-cookies)

If cookies are blocked you can't use them. If you need cookies, detect support by setting a cookie on the login page like `enabled=1` and then check for it in `/ws` handler. If it comes up blank and cookies are blocked you can try redirecting to `/please-enable-cookies` to ask the user to enable cookies for your site.

Another option is to store signed session data in local storage and include it in each request in the `Authorization` header. https://jwt.io/