# JavaScript solution to detect if third party cookie is disabled

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

My ultimate requirement is to detect if third party is enabled for the client browser because my payment gateway has a different scenario for browsers with disabled third party cookies.

I tried setting up google cookies from within an iframe within my page as below:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"  frameborder="0" style="border:0; display:none;"></iframe>
```

and was able to create third party cookies from google.

But I need to confirm "Is it really possible to read third party cookie?" because this way I can confirm that client browser has third party cookie enabled because I could read the cookies which google WAS ABLE to create.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read cookies from other sites. If you could, then you could get my login cookie from Google. That would be a horrific security problem.

What you can do is make sure the third party cookie is set by a site *that you control* and then communicate between the sites to indicate that it was set successfully (e.g. though [the `postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)).

Comment: @John — But useless to the OP because they can't read the result of their visitors using those tools.