# Session lost in Safari

Tags: facebook, session, iframe, safari

we have a facebook application. this project developted  with MVC 3. And we use data transfer with session. But the session was null when we changed page. 
For a solution we add some code at out project.

In global.asax add this;

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("P3P", "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADM DEV OUR BUS\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("P3P", "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"HONK\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");

    }
```

Then  add layout.cshtml this code;

`@{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
}`

finally add web.config ;

`<system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="20" />
...
</system.web>`

but we can't have a solution for this problem.

Comment: Check this question, here you'll get all the information you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working

Comment: Thanks, I read that before, but answers mostly about php and the others suggest cokkie. I want to learn another  solutions are possible.