# Jquery Cookie not being read correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, cookies, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set a cookie, and then read it and put it into my google geocoding script but it doesnt seem to work. It should be so the only autosuggestion results are from the US but you can see in the example that they are being suggested from every country.

This is the code I am working with:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/4/
```

This is the raw code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // SET COOKIE FOR TESTING   
$.cookie("country", "us");

    // GEOCODE RESULT
 function geocode(){
    var GeoCoded = { done: false };
    var input = document.getElementById('loc');
    var options = { types: []};
    var country_code = $.cookie('country');
    if (country_code) { options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': country_code }; }
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    $('#searchform').on('submit',function(e){
       if(GeoCoded.done)
            return true;
        e.preventDefault();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('loc').value;

        $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                GeoCoded.done = true;
                $('#searchform').submit();
            } else {
                $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',false);
                alert("Damn! We couldn't find this location")
            }

        });

    });

};      
</script>

<body onload="geocode()">
<form name="searchform">
        <input class="kw" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword"></input>
        <input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
        <input class="hidden" id="lat" disabled="true" placeholder="lat"></input>
        <input class="hidden" id="lng" disabled="true" placeholder="lng"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: When I type in location box, the auto-suggestions are from U.S. only.  If i change the cookie to ES, they are from Spain.  It appears to be working correctly.  Tried in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That's odd, when I run this code it doesn't work, I can type in "London" with either "es" or "us" and it still autosuggests me to have London, United Kingdom which it shouldnt do

Comment: If I set this line "var country_code = $.cookie('country');" to this "    var country_code = "us"; it works, so it must be an error reading the cookie

Comment: Still working for me: I added an alert on the cookie.  See what your result is.  http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/sR4GR/7/

Comment: Something definitely isn't right, even with this code it doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/9/

Comment: Even if I change the "country" to "country_new" so nothing has been set it still says undefined. After spending hours on this I am really stuck and would appreciate any help

Comment: Ok. I just checked on safari, and confirm what you have found. No cookie.  A quick google search shows issues with safari and ie.

Comment: I was using safari on iOS, and just checked the settings.  "Accept cookies" was set to "From Visited" - I changed to "Always", and now it's working fine.  I'd say your browser is set to not always accept cookies...   Your code is good.  Your browser is fighting you :)

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is written and executed correctly.  The cookie is set in Chrome and Firefox.  In Safari, the default cookie setting is **"From visited,"** which is a relatively strict setting.  To allow these cookies to be set, the user would have to change the Safari settings to allow cookies **"Always."**

While there doesn't seem to be a classy workaround for this, one possible resolution would be to check if the cookie returns `undefined` and if so, alert the user to "Please go to settings and turn on cookies so my awesome site can run effectively on your security-conscious device.  Mmkay? Thanks."

[This thread contains more information on Safari and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working).