# can localStorage totally replace 3rd party cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, security, local-storage

[Safari by default blocks third-party cookies dropped with iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working).

What is the disadvantage to simply replacing that functionality with `localStorage` in the same way, which it appears not to block? Are there any limitations on localStorage that do not exist with cookies?

```
<!-- filename localstorage.php -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (window.localStorage !== "undefined"){

        window.localStorage.user_id = "thomas123";

    }

</script>




<!-- filename call_localstorage.php -->
<iframe src="http://jsbin.com/UpelOcU/1/" width=1 height=1 border=0></iframe>

<script tyle="text/javascript">

    document.write(JSON.stringify(localStorage)); //{"user_id":"thomas123"}

</script>
```

Comment: localStorage requires JS to use, cookies are sniffable by a server.

Comment: so if you want server 'sniffable' vars u should use session vars ... cookies need to retire