# cookies are not stored from iframe - Laravel

Tags: ios, laravel, cookies, safari

I am using Laravel, an iframe from domain `a.com` shows my site at `b.com`, but in user can't log in to my site and no form can be submitted. It sounds `Safari` blocks all third party cookies (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478017/6934036) and old solutions not wording on newer version of safari.

Is there a new way to force safari to store cookies from the site in the iframe?

 And if there is no correct way, How can I Force Laravel to authenticate user via `local storage` instead of `cookies`?

**UPDATE:**

Cookies `SameSite` attributes are `None` with Secure flag.
Both sites use `HTTPS`.
it works correctly in chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. Could you find a solution for it?

Comment: @Mahsa Briefly, I've added some query string at the end of all URLs to recognize and login the user on each request, It's working.

Answer (score 0):

For third-party cookies, you need to specify the SameSite attribute as none.

```
SameSite=None
```

Also, many browsers currently require that `SameSite=None` cookies need also to have the `Secure` attribute, meaning that they require a secure context to prevent being observed by unauthorized devices.

Apple used to be very strict about security and privacy. So probably this is the reason why your cookies are not working.

Comment: Cookies `SameSite` attributes are `None`, it works correctly in chrome and Firefox, but not in IOS Safari